# Generalized Hardy operator and Lorentz gamma spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, metric-spaces

I would like to find an inequality which would 'place' the generalized Hardy operator $\int_0^th(y)dy\int_y^tk^*(s)ds$ in between two Lorentz gamma spaces.

Any literature or ideas would be greatly appreciated.